# Output a list/other data structure using linq query

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, linq-to-objects

is there a way to do a Console.WriteLine() on a Generic Collection 
example:
List a has:

```
a.Key[0]: apple
a.Value[0]: 1

a.Key[1]: bold
a.Value[2]: 2
```

Is there a way to write out the List contents: Key, Value using LINQ?

a = a.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value));

```
foreach (KeyValuePair pair in car) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ' : ' + pair.Value); 
}
```

Instead of the foreach I want to write a Linq / query...
is it possible?

Comment: is there any difference in performance if known? I am doing lookups mostly so using a Dictionary (instead of List as shown above) but for looping through to do the Console.WriteLine will the LINQ query be any faster than List or Dictionary directly used (if known)? Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you think about it, you're not really asking for a query. A query is essentially asking a question about data, and then arranging the answer in a particular manner. What you do with that answer is separate from actually generating it, though.

In your case, the "question" part of the query is "what is my data?" (since you didn't apply a Where clause,) and the "arrangement" part is "in descending order based on the Value of each item". You get an `IEnumerable<T>` which, when enumerated, will spit out your "answer".

At this point, you actually need to do something with the answer, so you enumerate it using a `foreach` loop, and then perform whatever actions you need on each item (like you do in your question.) I think this is a perfectly reasonable approach, that makes it clear what's going on.

If you absolutely must use a LINQ query, you can do this:

```
a.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList().ForEach(x => { Console.WriteLine(x.Key + ' : ' + x.Value); });
```

**EDIT**: This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) has more.

Answer (score 10):

There is an extension method which in itself loops over the values:

```
 myList.ForEach(a => {
      // You have access to each element here, but if you try to debug, this is only one function and won't be iterated in debug mode.
 });
```

Also you can use aggregate functions of link to concatenate strings together:

```
 Console.WriteLine(myList.Aggregate((a, b) => string.Format("{0}, {1}", a, b)));
```

Comment: This won't work with the code shown in the question, since `a` is `IEnumerable<T>` and `ForEach()` is member of `List<T>`.

Answer (score 6):

You can construct string using LINQ and then outputs it to console
Example:

```
var s=string.Join(Environment.NewLine, a.Select(x=>string.Format("{0}:{1}",x.Key,x.Value)).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: At first I thought "Who on earth would do such a thing just to output to the console"? But then I realized that if you use Linq then you can easily order the list by x.Key (and do filtering within the list)--something that wouldn't be so easy if a foreach loop had been used instead.