# I want to display information from my collection List<Astronaut> c#

Tags: c#, collections

my code:

```
var infoForMax = allmission.Where(miss => (miss.end - miss.start) == proba2)
                .Select(miss=>(miss.start, miss.end,miss.crew,miss.spaceship)).ToList();

            foreach (var item in infoForMax)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
```

Also Tried to prescribe an enumerator.The same result

What i see in console:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing out the results of my linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652832/printing-out-the-results-of-my-linq-query) and [Output a list/other data structure using linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606274/output-a-list-other-data-structure-using-linq-query)

Answer (score 0):

Hooray, I did it myself) Here's my decision

```
var out1_2 = $"";
            foreach (var item in infoForMax)
            {
                
                out1_2 +=  item.start;
                out1_2 += $" ";
                out1_2 +=  item.end;
                out1_2 += $" ";
                foreach (var item2 in item.crew)
                {
                    out1_2 += item2;
                    out1_2 += $" || ";
                }
                out1_2 += item.spaceship;

            }

            Console.WriteLine(out1_2);
```

Comment: You can considerably simplify this code and do a lot of refactoring: good practice to you! Take a look at [String Interpolation In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/string-interpolation-in-C-Sharp-6-0/) and [String Interpolation In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understanding-string-interpolation-in-c-sharp/) and [String interpolation in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation)